# slicing string in pandas data frame and assign a new column

Tags: python, string, pandas

Hi I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = ['P. John','Merry','P. John travis']
df['First_Name'] = df.Name.str.split('.', expand = True)[0]
df['Last_Name'] = df.Name.str.split('.', expand = True)[1]
```

I want to slice the column base on period "." and used as last name.
I could do for all but for "merry" it shows **None** as follow:

```
0            John
1            None
2     John travis
```

How could I replace with all **None** in **last name** with **First Name**?
A searched in the forum and could not find one.

And second question is that I have another data frame as follow:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Merry','John travis'],"Position":['CEO','CTO','Engr']})
```

I am creating a new column ** Position** for df by using map function.

```
 df ['Position'] = df.Last_Name.map (df1.set_index('Name').Position)
```

but the new column in df show me some Nan value as follow:
[image]

The data frame I shown in this post replicates the real problem that I am solving.
However, using the map fucntion in real problem give me the follwoing error code:

> Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.

Can anyone advise me on that.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code by one `split` with parameter `n=1`  for split by first `.` if possible multiple one and then replace `None` by `fillna`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['P. John','Merry','P. John travis']})

df[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']] = df.Name.str.split('.\s+', expand = True, n=1)
#if always only one .
#df[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']] = df.Name.str.split('.\s+', expand = True, n=1)
df['Last_Name'] = df['Last_Name'].fillna(df['First_Name'])
print (df)
             Name First_Name     Last_Name
0         P. John          P          John
1           Merry      Merry         Merry
2  P. John travis          P   John travis
```

Or remove `expand=True` for `Series of list`s and select first and last values:

```
splitted = df.Name.str.split('.\s+', n=1)
df['first_Name'] = splitted.str[0]
df['Last_Name'] = splitted.str[-1]
print (df)
             Name first_Name     Last_Name
0         P. John          P          John
1           Merry      Merry         Merry
2  P. John travis          P   John travis
```

Comment: Thanks Jez. You helped me through out my learning journey. Appreciate much on that.

Comment: @Zephyr - I try improve your solution ;)

Comment: Hi Jez, Thanks. While continuing above example, I have some issue in using map function. I.e. I have two data frames for the same persons in df. i was trying to use map function, and found NaN value in creating new column.
I edited the question above. Thanks

Comment: @Zephyr - First problem is you need split by `.` and whitespace, edited answer.

Comment: @Zephyr - Problem is duplicates in `df1.Name` like `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Merry','John travis', 'John'],
                    "Position":['CEO','CTO','Engr', 'boss']})`, solution is remove dupes by `df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'])` or better `df['Position'] = df.Last_Name.map (df1.groupby('Name').Position.apply(', '.join))`

Comment: Yeah. I found out two exact same names with two positions from different teams. Your second solution would solve the problem, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177265/discussion-between-zephyr-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

Using `fillna`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = ['P. John','Merry','P. John travis']
df['First_Name'] = df.Name.str.split('.', expand = True)[0]
df['Last_Name'] = (df.Name.str.split('.', expand = True)[1]).fillna(df["First_Name"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             Name First_Name     Last_Name
0         P. John          P          John
1           Merry      Merry         Merry
2  P. John travis          P   John travis
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. Appreciate much.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a list comprehension and negative indexing

```
df['Last_Name'] = [x.split('.')[-1] for x in df.Name]

             Name     Last_Name
0         P. John          John
1           Merry         Merry
2  P. John travis   John travis
```

here's an extension of the above technique that returns a whole new dataframe with the name split as desired, *in a single statement*

```
pd.DataFrame([(lambda x: (y, x[0], x[-1]))(y.split('.')) 
              for y in df.Name], 
             columns=['Name', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name'])

             Name First_Name     Last_Name
0         P. John          P          John
1           Merry      Merry         Merry
2  P. John travis          P   John travis
```